# Creating a modal with JavaScript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a link that I want a modal to pop up when I click on it of a different HTML page is there a way to do so using either JavaScript or Jquery. It is pretty much a resume card that opens a modal of my resume.html page. I have posted the resume card and the resuume.html code below. Is there a way to create a modal from a different page or at least its main tag because that is all I need really.

```html
<a href="">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-top">
                            <h2>Resume</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-bottom">
                            <p>I would like to share my resume with whoever it may concern that outlining all the achievements and skills I have achieved.</p>
                            <button>See More</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="personal.css">
    <title>Resume</title>
</head>
<body class="resume">
    <main class="container">
        <section class="resume-section flex-resume">
            <div class="info">
                <h1>Alladin Assaf</h1>
                <h2>Web Designer - Front-End</h2>
                <p>219 Moss Hill Dr Arlington, Tx 76018</p>
                <p>Phone: 682-313-3458</p>
                <p>Email: alladin.assaf@icloud.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="paragraph">
                <p>Hello, I am a recent graduate of the University of Texas at Arlington majoring in Communication Technology. I am a well detailed individual and I love using my creativity to develop visually pleasing websites. In my free time I love to play video games and hang out with friends. </p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="resume-section">
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li>Tarrant County College (2017-2019)</li>
                <li>University of Texas at Arlington (2019 - 2021)</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="resume-section">
            <h2>Skills</h2>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li>HTML</li>
                <li>CSS</li>
                <li>SCSS</li>
                <li>JavaScript</li>
                <li>Jquery</li>
                <li>PHP</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="resume-section">
            <h2>Certificates</h2>
            <hr>
            <ul>
                <li>Digital Media certificate</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this as in below snippet . And can decorate resume according to need .

```js
function showResume(){
document.getElementById("resume").style.display = "block";
}

function closeResume(){
document.getElementById("resume").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#resume {
  display: none;
  border:2px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  background-color:white
}

.close{
position:absolute;
right:0;
padding: 8px;
background-color:red;
color:white;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
  <a href="#">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-top">
          <h2>Resume</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-bottom">
          <p>I would like to share my resume with whoever it may concern that outlining all the achievements and skills I have achieved.</p>
          <button onclick="showResume()">See More</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>

  <div id="resume">
  <span class="close" onclick="closeResume()">Close</span>
    <main class="container">
      <section class="resume-section flex-resume">
        <div class="info">
          <h1>Alladin Assaf</h1>
          <h2>Web Designer - Front-End</h2>
          <p>219 Moss Hill Dr Arlington, Tx 76018</p>
          <p>Phone: 682-313-3458</p>
          <p>Email: alladin.assaf@icloud.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
          <p>Hello, I am a recent graduate of the University of Texas at Arlington majoring in Communication Technology. I am a well detailed individual and I love using my creativity to develop visually pleasing websites. In my free time I love to play
            video games and hang out with friends. </p>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="resume-section">
        <h2>Education</h2>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>Tarrant County College (2017-2019)</li>
          <li>University of Texas at Arlington (2019 - 2021)</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section class="resume-section">
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>SCSS</li>
          <li>JavaScript</li>
          <li>Jquery</li>
          <li>PHP</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section class="resume-section">
        <h2>Certificates</h2>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>Digital Media certificate</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
```

You can now share your website link and it will first show the card then your resume . You can also hide/show card like adding this to the **JS** function :
`document.getElementsByClassName("card").style.display = "none/block";`
respectively